# PowerBI--Custom Column--Multiple Condition IF statements

Tags: powerbi, dax

Beginner here, desperate for your help.

Basically, I need a new column to take the value of either column shown in the image, unless both columns are null.  If both are null, then the new column should say "No discipline entered".

My version of PowerBI only has add a custom column option in the edit queries window.  I have tried working the below solutions, but I obviously have a concept error and not using the solutions appropriately.
I appreciate your patience and assistance!

[Custom Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rv0xv.jpg)
[Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKkhV.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

The reason you are getting "Expression.Error: The name..." errors is because your are trying to enter DAX formulas in Power Query editor. Power Query uses a different language called "M", and does not recognize DAX. You can solve this problem in 2 ways:

1) Exit query editor, and in PowerBI window, go to tab "Modeling" and create "New Column". Enter DAX formulas there;

2) If you prefer to solve the problem in Power Query, create a custom column there and enter this "M" formula:

```
each List.First(List.RemoveNulls({[PIDISK], [PI_DISK]}), "No Disk Entered"))
```

How the formula works: List.RemoveNulls removes nulls from the list of columns you provide. Then it picks the first value from the result; if there is none, it uses default option ("no disk entered"). Just make sure that your NULLs are really nulls.

Comment: I really appreciate your help.  I have so much to learn, even regarding how to ask the right questions.  I will study up on M and you have a great day sir!

Answer (score 1):

Whats up? Either of these should work depending on whether or not you have "null" strings or blank() values:

"null"

```
New Column =
SWITCH (
    TRUE (),
    AND ( [PIDISC] = "null", [PI_DISC] = "null" ), "NO DISC ENTERED",
    [PIDISC] = "null", [PI_DISC],
    [PI_DISC] = "null", [PIDISC]
)
```

Tested:

[image]

BLANK()

```
New Column =
SWITCH (
    TRUE (),
    AND ( ISBLANK([PIDISC]), ISBLANK([PI_DISC]) ) , "NO DISC ENTERED",
    ISBLANK ( [PIDISC] ), [PI_DISC],
    ISBLANK ( [PI_DISC] ), [PIDISC]
)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to do this in DAX, I recommend using the `SWITCH ( TRUE() ...)` method in lieu of nested if statements (which [this article](https://powerpivotpro.com/2015/03/the-diabolical-genius-of-switch-true/) explains beautifully). I believe this should produce the desired result; based upon your screenshot I assumed those nulls were text strings vs. `NULL`. If it is a true `NULL`, PowerBI uses `BLANK()`.

```
= SWITCH (
    TRUE (),
    [PIDISC] <> "null", [PIDISC],
    [PI_DISC] <> "null", [PI_DISC],
    "no disc entered"
)
```

The first condition that evaluates to `TRUE()` will take precedence.

Comment: Thank you, but I am getting the 'Expression.Error: The name 'SWITCH' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly' after entering the above in the 'custom column formula' field.

Answer (score 0):

A nested `IF` isn't too bad for this:

```
IF([PIDISC] = "null" && [PI_DISC] = "null",
   "NO DISC ENTERED,
   IF([PIDISC] = "null",
      [PI_DISC],
      [PIDISC]
   )
)
```

or

```
IF([PIDISC] <> "null",
   [PIDISC],
   IF([PI_DISC] <> "null",
      [PI_DISC],
      "NO DISC ENTERED"
   )
)
```

---

If those are blanks rather than text "null", then it might look a bit different.

```
IF(ISLBANK([PIDISC]) && ISBLANK([PI_DISC]),
   "NO DISC ENTERED,
   IF(ISLBANK([PIDISC]),
      [PI_DISC],
      [PIDISC]
   )
)
```

or

```
IF(NOT(ISLBANK([PIDISC])),
   [PIDISC],
   IF(NOT(ISBLANK([PI_DISC]),
      [PI_DISC],
      "NO DISC ENTERED"
   )
)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Since you are trying to work in the query editor, your M language custom column might look like this:

```
if [PIDISC] = "null" and [PI_DISC] = "null"
 then "NO DISC ENTERED"
else if [PIDISC] = "null" then [PI_DISC]
else if [PI_DISC] = "null" then [PIDISC]
else "Else Condition"
```

or

```
if [PIDISC] = "" and [PI_DISC] = "" then "NO DISC ENTERED"
else if [PIDISC] = "" then [PI_DISC]
else if [PI_DISC] = "" then [PIDISC]
else "Else Condition"
```

Comment: Thank you , but I get the 'Expression.Error: The name 'IF' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly'  Still working on it.....thanks.  Let me see if I can put more effort in.

Comment: RADO is correct. You asked for DAX but are trying to use it in the query editor which doesn't use DAX.

Comment: Thank you.  I have a few concept errors that I am working to resolve with your help.